# In virtual table click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

click function is not working. I don,t know the reason

```
$("img[id^='down']").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
});
```

after collect some data, a table is display in browser with down image. i need click function for that image but its not working

[image]

please help me where iam wrong

Comment: Does table load using ajax?

Comment: yes, Inside rd.onload = function(e) and ajax call also used

Comment: You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). `$(document).on('click', "img[id^='down']", function...`

Comment: @Mohammad its work thank you so much. Can you add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your target element doesn't exist on page load and it loaded using ajax, the

```
$("img[id^='down']").click(...
```

doesn't work. You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). So your code should changed to

```
$(document).on('click', "img[id^='down']", function(){
    alert("hi");
})
```